# Although I set timezone configration, Carbon::now() timezone never change on Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I wrote this program in app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php

```
public function testCarbon()
    {
        return Carbon::now();
    }
```

and access response is

```
"2019-10-10T06:00:26.339861Z"
```

but my expect result is about 2019-10-10 15:00.

although result on `php artisan tinker` is correct time, but access response is not.

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.3.3 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Carbon\Carbon::now();
=> Carbon\Carbon @1570687584 {#3006
     date: 2019-10-10 15:06:24.967710 Asia/Tokyo (+09:00),
   }
```

I tried those below

change config/app.php

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Tokyo',
```

then

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

change C:\xampp\php\php.ini

```
date.timezone=Asia/Tokyo
```

Somebody please help, thank you.

Comment: have you try to change timezone in  `config/app.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to format the date to your desired format. you can modify the function as follows:

```
public function testCarbon()
{
    $date = Carbon::now();
    return $date->format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works! I wonder why correct works on tinker, but on script is not. is it only way?

Comment: Tinker formats data for making it easy for the viewer. In contrast, when you called Carbon in your controller, it returns you the raw data without any formation. So, you needed to format it manually as you want. If my answer is right, then please mark it as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your app time zone by configuring app.php file in config folder .
To change time zone , modify the value of timezone in app.php file.

[list of timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Hope this will help.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I already tried that as I wrote.

Comment: i'm testing on my local apps and get different value for use `Carbon::now()` and `Carbon::now('UTC')`